# Outlook reply to all gets sent to me, but my address appears nowhere

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm using Outlook 2016 for a few days now. When I reply-all to any email containing more than one address, the email is also sent to me, or at least a copy appears on my inbox.

Please note, my address **does not** appear on the To, Cc or Bcc while I'm composing the reply.

I've searched for a solution everywhere, but I've only found instances where people reply-all and the sender's address is wrongly appearing on the To/Cc/Bcc.

If it helps, I'm using IMAP and this behavior did not occur while using Outlook 2010.

Comment: Reply to all automatically includes the person to whom the initial message was sent to.

Comment: I understand that, but my address is not being included in the To, Cc or Bcc. How can this be possible?